# if $\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}|u_j|^p<\infty$, is then $u_j\to 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $u\in l^p(\mathbb{Z})$ with $1<p<\infty$ and $p$ is fixed. Per definition it is $\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}|u_j|^p<\infty$. Does follow $u_j\to 0$ for $j\to \infty$?

I already know that $sup_j|u_j|<\infty$ and $|u_j|^p\to 0$. But I'm not sure how to conclude that $|u_j|\to 0$ for $j\to \infty$. Can you help me?

Comment: Where does the continuous function $f:x\mapsto x^{1/p}$, defined on $[0,\infty[$, take the value 0? Think it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. f takes the value 0 only in $x=0$. But I don't know why this is important for my question

Comment: Note that $|u_j|=(|u_j|^p)^{1/p}$ and $f$ is continuous. Since $|u_j|^p\to 0$, you have $|u_j|\to 0$.